# How do I set up an automated rubber farm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-forestry

What would be a simple setup for an automated rubber farm? I know there exists an automated treetap and a rubber farm block, but I've read the latter is deprecated. So, how do I set up such a farm?

Comment: Are you asking the simplest way to setup a Foresty Multifarm configured to farm only rubber?

Comment: @Ender Yes, possibly with instructions how to attach it to a extractor.

Comment: Are you able to use RedPower2?

Comment: @imulsion yes, I use direwolf20.

Comment: I'll add this as a comment seeing as i was actually planning on trying this in my own server. I currently have a tree-farm setup with steve's carts2. Now if you get 2-3 rubbertree sapplings, and you add these to a new track of steve's carts you should be able to get a propper farm going. Now the reason i dont just set this as an anwer but as a comment is that a rubber tree doesnt always drop a sapling and sometimes it drops multiple. I'll try this tonight and add an answer if i managed to get this automated.

Comment: if you have minefactory (I think) you could set up a planter and harvester combo. A bit of a pain, when you factor in all the sewage and fertilizer. (but you only need those if you want to bump up the speed of the growth.) you could stand there with bone meal. or set up a few of them. but without some sort of growth boost. it would only harvest at the speed that the trees would grow. With this method you would also get wood and saplings as well as the resin or rubber.

Answer (score 2):

Since the pack  has MineFactoryReloaded, I would look into using the Planter and Harvester with MFR's rubber trees. The rubber should be interchangeable with IC2 Rubber because of the ore dictionary. You should also be able to use the harvester and planter with the IC2 Rubber trees, but I think that is less productive. On the other hand you'll produce lots of rubber wood which could be used as wood, or tossed into an IC2 Extractor to get more rubber.